# insertionsort algorithm for an unordered list

Tags: python, list

I want to ask a question about ordering a list.

I was asked to create a function that inserts an integer into an ordered list without using any Python modules.

This is what I created below:

```
def insert_in_order(num, ordered_list):
position = 0
    for item in ordered_list:
        if num > item:
            position += 1
    ordered_list[position:position] = [num]
    return ordered_list
```

This functions well.

The following outputs are observed:

```
insert_in_order(3, [1, 2, 4, 5])
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

olist = list(range(0, 20, 3))
insert_in_order(8, olist)
>> [0, 3, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15, 18]
```

I was then asked to use the function `insert_in_order` to order an unordered list 
such as `[91, 80, 34, 4]` and I attemped this in a number of ways.

```
def insert_sort(unordered_list):
    ordered_list = []
    for item in unordered_list:
        ordered_list = insert_in_order(item, unordered_list)
```

This, however, does not produce the result I desire, as it endlessly keeps on going by adding each item to the list more than once.

How can I use my original function and modify the line in the code to order an unordered list?

Comment: You almost have it. But think about it, you need to insert, in order, *into the ordered list*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def insert_sort(unordered_list):
    ordered_list = []
    for item in unordered_list:
        ordered_list = insert_in_order(item, ordered_list)
    return ordered_list
```

Now take a close look to find where it differs from your code ;-)

Comment: this simply returns `[91]` and nothing more

Comment: Sorry, yes, the last line was missing.

Comment: Oh my god I had that line indented when I inserted it myself haha it was meant to be in line with the `for` keyword than the `ordered_list` - thanks so much!

Comment: BTW, the title of your question is misleading - this algorithm, known as insertionsort, has nothing to do with bisection.

Comment: One question, does the `return` keyword function in the same way for a `for` loop like the keyword `break` would for a `while` loop in the sense that it breaks the loop completely?

Comment: I've retitled the question too.

Comment: It return from the function - if used inside a loop (be it `for` or `while` loop), it ends the loop, but unlike `break` does not proceed to the code following the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start with your ordered list. In your code you are adding to your unordered list while iterating over it at the same time. This creates the infinite loop. 
try:

`ordered_list = insert_in_order(item, ordered_list)`

Comment: I understand but this simply returns `[91]` and nothing more!